# SAS EG: Prompts with Dynamic List on Metaserver

Tags: sas, prompt, enterprise-guide, dynamic-list, sas-metadata

I'm trying to develop a SAS Prompt that has a drop down with values pulled from a field on a table I'm storing in the Work library.

When I click "Browse" in the "Data Source" area, I'm confined to my SAS Folders.

I'm on a metadata server and don't yet understand the limitations.

How would it be possible to store a table in the SAS "My Folder" folder?

I've created a static list from the data. Should I use this option instead? If so, is there a way to update the list using a SAS Script?

I'm new to SAS EG but not Base SAS. I'm not familiar with "Files" or the "Metadata Server". I typically just query data out of multiple libraries and store in in a work folder prior to export.

Comment: `metadata server` not `meta server`, though I do enjoy the concept of a meta server...

Answer (score 2):

The SAS Metadata Server stores metadata about your EG project in the metadata server repository. The actual project files are stored on the WebDAV server. Regular users do not need to know about the WebDAV server. The important part to know is that the metadata server repository in your case acts like a file system. On that file system, your system administrator must have granted rights (with ACTs and ACEs).

Since 2011, the [recommended best practice from SAS](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/376-2011.pdf) is to DENY rights initially, and ALLOW rights on a basis of need.

SAS prompts consist of metadata only. They are read by the SAS Prompting Framework which take care of the user interface. As such, you do not need to store them in you WORK library. Instead, SAS EG jobs can take parameters from the Prompting Framework, and you can use the parameters as SAS Macro variables in your SAS EG code.

To use a table with EG you must have been granted to enterprise resources. If you want to use local resources, you must be able to import Excelsheets via the File menu.

The biggest difference between SAS Foundation and Enterprise Guide (with Metadata Server) is that

- on SAS Foundation, you and your team can access everthing, and need to do every yourselves (including documentation)
- and EG / MS tasks are split up in different interfaces to be more scalable over the entire Enterprise (company wise). All relations between entities are stored in the metadata server and are automatically documented / graphable. You as a developer are a bit more dependant of others, roles are split up, like with autorisation in your case. For larger organisations to be compliant this situation is generally considered an improvement.

For more information please see the [SAS Intelligence Platform Overview documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/biov/69018/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm).